# Should I send an email to remind the hiring manager?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, recruitment, email, follow-up

I was interviewed by the Vice president on Monday, and I met the hiring managers as well.

The HR manager said they would get back to me on Wednesday, and said they would hopefully fill the whole office by the beginning of November.

So today is the day. Do you think it is a good idea to send the hr managers an email, so they can reply me back? I thought it would not be necessary but they don't have to dig my contact info in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think it is a good idea to send the hr managers an email, so they can reply me back?

They said Wednesday, and it is still that day, so the mail may arrive at any moment now, just be patient. They already have your information, and they can surely look on it for your email *if* they want to contact you.

Usually you still may want to wait a bit more, as those processes are not always deterministic, and tend to take more time in some cases. I usually wait a day or two before politely reminding them in the cases I get a definite date from them. In other situations I have even waited a week before replying, more than that may be considered as too long to wait.

I suggest you try to keep your options open and continue looking for other jobs you may like. Also, have in mind that even though it would be good for them to reply to you even though you were declined, nothing is bounding them to do so, so it is a possibility that in some cases recruiters never reply back.